# AngularJS string replace in HTML

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs

In my `AngularJS` application, I have an issue with string replace in HTML.

**Expectation:**

Using the same variable as section title and partial of button's label.

```
Submitted Forms (Form (13G), Form (12C) and etc.,)
Attach Submitted Forms

Planned Plans (Plan (13G), Plan (12C) and etc.,)
Attach Planned Plans

Defined Schemes (Scheme (13G), Scheme (12C) and etc.,)
Attach Defined Schemes

Paid Insurances (Insurance (13G), Insurance (12C) and etc.,)
Attach Paid Insurances
```

**Scenario:**

I have headerText `$scope` variable. It contains the `LabelName`s of each section:

```
$scope.headerText = [{
    LabelName: 'Submitted Forms (Form (13G), Form (12C) and etc.,)'
}, {
    LabelName: 'Planned Plans (Plan (16K), Plan (12C) and etc.,)'
}, {
    LabelName: 'Defined Schemes (Scheme (11H), Scheme (12C) and etc.,)'
}, {
   LabelName: 'Paid Insurances (Insurance (10G), Insurance (12C) and etc.,)'
}];
```

This `LabelName` should be the title for each section and the same `LabelName` need to be used for the button's label text along with the text `Attach` and also need to remove the text in between the brackets.

So in the HTML file, I tried the below code to achieve the result:

```
<div ng-repeat="header in headerText">
    <span ng-bind="header.LabelName"></span>
    <br />
    <button>{{addText.replace("{0}", header.LabelName).replace(/(\(.*\))/g, '')}}</button>
    <hr />
</div>
```

Mean, I want to replace the content with brackets along with empty space
**(Form (13G), Form (12C) and etc.,)**  
from 
**Submitted Forms (Form (13G), Form (12C) and etc.,)** 
and to use that in the button's label text.

I tried the regexp `.replace(/(\(.*\))/g, '')`, but it is not supporting.

Is there any way to achieve this in `HTML` itself.

[`Sample Plunker`](http://plnkr.co/edit/zOjBUtnJqdQvalNkt32J)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Move the javascript to script.js and return the value

```js
angular.module('app', []);

function StringCtrl($scope) {

  $scope.headerText = [{
    LabelName: 'Submitted Forms (Form (13G), Form (12C) and etc.,)'
  }, {
    LabelName: 'Planned Plans (Plan (13G), Plan (12C) and etc.,)'
  }, {
    LabelName: 'Defined Schemes (Scheme (13G), Scheme (12C) and etc.,)'
  }, {
    LabelName: 'Paid Insurances (Insurance (13G), Insurance (12C) and etc.,)'
  }];

  $scope.addText = 'Attach {0}';
  $scope.getText = function(obj){
    return $scope.addText.replace("{0}", obj).replace(/(\(.*\))/g, '')
  };

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="StringCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="header in headerText">
    <span ng-bind="header.LabelName"></span>
    <br />
    <button ng-bind="getText(header.LabelName)"></button>
    <hr />
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: My actual expectation is to achieve the `regexp' in html itself, hope thats not possible to do in html.This is fine..

Comment: @Arulkumar For javascript code that is complex it is better to make a method in controller and call it from view.

Comment: yeah, i understand the complexity. This fix is helpful.

Answer (score 6):

It would be much better to create a method for that purpose:

```
var addText = 'Attach {0}';
$scope.getButtonLabel = function(label){
  return addText.replace('{0}', label.substr(0,label.indexOf("(")));
};
```

And then use it in your markup:

```
<button>{{getButtonLabel(header.LabelName)}}</button>
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/LZhNbjQW2r9Kz2JCAQqQ?p=preview)

Answer (score 4):

You can create variable in component for regex.

```
myReg = /'/g;
```

and reference the variable in replace method as below

```
<span>{{element.configMetadata.replace(myReg , "\"")}}</span>
```

Answer (score 3):

Better of to create a directive to make the split and have the dynamic text be calculated inside the directive.

Code:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [])
    .directive('splButton', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            label: '='
        },
        template: '<button>{{btnText}}</button>',
        controller: function ($scope) {
            $scope.btnText = "Attached " + $scope.label.split('(')[0];
        }
    };
})
    .controller("stringCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.headerText = [{
        LabelName: 'Submitted Forms(Form(13G), Form(12C) and etc., )'
    }, {
        LabelName: 'Planned Plans(Plan(13G), Plan(12C) and etc., )'
    }, {
        LabelName: 'Defined Schemes(Scheme(13G), Scheme(12C) and etc., )'
    }, {
        LabelName: 'Paid Insurances(Insurance(13G), Insurance(12C) and etc., )'
    }];
});
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qjqe2vqd/)