# how can i dynamically add an element to an Angular view during runtime?

Tags: html, angular

I have declared the following input field.

```
public inputField = '<input class="form-control autofocus tertiary-bg-color answerField" 
type="text" required '
  + ' [(ngModel)]="userAnswer" #userAnswerVar="ngModel"'
  + ' name="userAnswer" placeholder="Enter your answer here" '
  + ' (change)="processAnswer()" [disabled]="answer !== null">'
```

I have a series of questions that have static underscores at varying locations within each questions. I.e.,

```
Newton’s __________ Law of Motion states that an object in motion will stay in motion and an 
object at rest will stay at rest, unless it is acted upon by an external force.
```

What I wish to do is replace every instance of _________ with the above input field such that the user can enter data within. In my component, I attempt to replace the underscores in the statement with the input field like this:

```
 this.blankField = this.fillInBlank?.question.replace('__________', this.inputField)
```

When the html is launched:

```
<div class="mb-2">
    <span class="me-2">{{fibNumber}}.</span>
    <span class="fw-semibold primary-color">{{blankField}} 
    </span>
</div>
```

blankfield replaces the underscores as literal text instead of an html element.

```
Newton’s <input class="form-control autofocus tertiary-bg-color answerField" type="text" 
required [(ngModel)]="userAnswer" #userAnswerVar="ngModel" name="userAnswer" 
placeholder="Enter your answer here" (change)="processAnswer()" [disabled]="answer !== null"> 
Law of Motion states that an object in motion will stay in motion and an object at rest will 
stay at rest, unless it is acted upon by an external force.
```

Comment: I am not an angular geek but you could think of going this way instead https://stackoverflow.com/a/29031706/1982631

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used Angular Renderer2 to dynamically add classes, attributes and properties. Note, Renderer2 does not handle [(ngModel)], disabled and (change) so the input element was statically sent to the directive, it was never processed by the directive. If [(ngModel)], disabled or (change) are processed by any Renderer2 functions, they will simply disappear from the input element.

Here is the native element that is passed to the directive to add classes and attributes:

```
<span class="fw-semibold primary-color" [appReplaceUnderscores]="fillInBlank.question">
        <input [(ngModel)]="userAnswer"
            class="form-control autofocus tertiary-bg-color answerField d-inline" 
            type="text" 
            required 
            name="userAnswer" 
            placeholder="Enter your answer here" 
            (change)="processAnswer()" 
            [disabled]="answer !== null">
    </span>
```

Here is the directive that does the work:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appReplaceUnderscores]'
})
   export class ReplaceUnderscoresDirective {
       @Input() set appReplaceUnderscores(question) {
        console.log('question', question)
        this.replaceUnderscore(question)
      }

  constructor(
    private el: ElementRef<HTMLElement>,
    private renderer:Renderer2
   ) {
    console.log(this.el.nativeElement);
  }

  private replaceUnderscore = (question) => {
    const nativeElement: HTMLElement = this.el.nativeElement;  

    let inputNode = null;

    Array.from(nativeElement.childNodes).forEach(node => {

      if(node.nodeName === 'INPUT') {
        inputNode = node;
      } else {
        this.renderer.removeChild(nativeElement, node)   
      }      
    })

    const splits = question.split('__________')

    const textBeforeUnderscores = this.renderer?.createText(splits[0]);
    const textAfterUnderscores = this.renderer?.createText(splits[1]);

    const spanBeforeInput = this.renderer?.createElement('span');
    this.renderer?.appendChild(spanBeforeInput, textBeforeUnderscores);    
    this.renderer.addClass(spanBeforeInput, "d-inline")
    console.log('spanBeforeInput', spanBeforeInput)

    const spanAfterInput = this.renderer?.createElement('span');
    this.renderer?.appendChild(spanAfterInput, textAfterUnderscores);
    this.renderer.addClass(spanAfterInput, "d-inline")

    this.renderer.insertBefore(nativeElement, spanBeforeInput, inputNode)
    this.renderer?.appendChild(nativeElement, spanAfterInput);  
  }

}
```